# Invalid_argument "String.sub / Bytes.sub"

Tags: recursion, types, ocaml, recurrence

I have a small problem on an exercice that i'm doing.
I try to recursively count vowels in a String but i have this strange error popping. 
Can someone explain me why ?

```
  let rec nb_voyelle = function chaine ->
                           if chaine == "" then
                             0
                           else
                             let length = (String.length chaine)-1 in
                             let p_length = String.sub chaine 0 length in
                             match chaine.[length] with
                             | 'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' | 'y' -> 1 + nb_voyelle p_length
                             | _ -> 0 + nb_voyelle p_length

    ;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is i used "==" to compare the string in my final case which is not the good pervasive to test equality between two elements.

As such, the case (String.sub "" 0 -1) happens and the function fail raising this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please accept your answer once you are able to.